# How to display markers one by one on processing maps?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, processing

I am using [Unfolding Maps](http://unfoldingmaps.org) to visualize some location data on Google Maps. I have several locations which I need to display one by one like a person's traveled path. I tried using delays and program got freezed. Can you suggest me a proper way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Show your attempt, if you will.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add quotes here in stack overflow? It shows and error saying that code is not properly formatted. Pls help

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do so best would be - as v.k. suggested - to give an example.

Comment: I've uploaded my code here
https://www.sendspace.com/file/dz7ck2

When you run the code you will see that all the markers are placed on the map at once. Those locations are in an array. I need to display one by one so that I can see that as an animation. Thanks, hope this clarifies what I am trying to do.

Comment: Didn't download the code (NB: it would be better to share the code as [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but why not try using an index for the array which you increase over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;

UnfoldingMap map;
ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
int locationIndex = -1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  // Test data. Load your actual data, instead:
  locations.add(new Location(53, 0));
  locations.add(new Location(12, 50));
}

void draw() {
  map.draw();

  // Simple animation: Every 60 frames show next location 
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) {
    // Increase only if more data exists
    if (locationIndex < locations.size() - 1) {
      locationIndex++;
    }
  }

  // Show all currently visible locations (i.e. 0 - index)
  for (int i = 0; i <= locationIndex; i++) {
    Location location = locations.get(i);
    ScreenPosition pos = map.getScreenPosition(location);
    ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. This is something similar I was looking for. Thanks for your effort.